# RDS Environment variables not available to Elastic Beanstalk instance on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After creating a Java 8 Elastic Beanstalk instance with RDS, the RDS connection details are not visible as environment variables (they are visible on other instances that are running).

After running `printenv` command, the expectation was for these values to be available but they are not.

> RDS_HOSTNAME=foo.com
>
> RDS_USERNAME=foo
>
> RDS_PASS=bar

These are required by the server config

```
database:
    driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    user: ${RDS_USERNAME}
    password: ${RDS_PASSWORD}
    url: jdbc:mysql://${RDS_HOSTNAME}/${RDS_DB_NAME}
```

During application firing they are not available, the logs shows a Java exception that it cannot find the environment variables.

> io.dropwizard.configuration.UndefinedEnvironmentVariableException: The environment variable 'RDS_USERNAME' is not defined; could not substitute the expression '${RDS_USERNAME}'.
>       at io.dropwizard.configuration.EnvironmentVariableLookup.lookup(EnvironmentVariableLookup.java:41)
>       at org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor.resolveVariable(StrSubstitutor.java:934)
>       at org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor.substitute(StrSubstitutor.java:855)
>       at org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor.substitute(StrSubstitutor.java:743)
>       at org.apache.commons.lang3.text.StrSubstitutor.replace(StrSubstitutor.java:403)
>       at io.dropwizard.configuration.SubstitutingSourceProvider.open(SubstitutingSourceProvider.java:39)
>       at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:83)
>       at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:124)
>       at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:72)
>       at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
>       at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)

However if I run the following command on the ec2 instance

```
sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment
```

It prints the values out in JSON:

```
{"CONFIG":"dev.yml","RDS_HOSTNAME":"foo.com","RDS_PASSWORD":"foo","M2":"/usr/local/apache-maven/bin","M2_HOME":"/usr/local/apache-maven","RDS_DB_NAME":"foo","JAVA_HOME":"/usr/lib/jvm/java","RDS_USERNAME":"foo","GRADLE_HOME":"/usr/local/gradle","RDS_PORT":"3306"}
```

Any ideas how to restore these values for the ec2-user?

I have tried:

- Restarting the EB instance
- Rebuilding the instance
- `cat` the values into a script that sets them after `eb deploy`

Any ideas, why they are not visible on this particular instance?

**Instance details**

```
  Environment details foo: foo-service
  Application name: foo-service
  Region: eu-west-2
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-2::platform/Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.6.0
  Tier: WebServer-Standard
```

Comment: Can you try to initialize them in /etc/environment? When I need to be sure an environment variable exists I make sure and add it there. All user shells will get that variable set that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out, AWS won't expose the environment variables directly in your OS as we expected:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-env-variables-shell/

Answer (score 1):

I would run the EB environment update and or replace the Instance. Or you can move to ["Storing the Connection String in Amazon S3"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html)

> When the environment update is complete, the DB instance's hostname
>   and other connection information are available to your application
>   through the following environment properties:
>
> RDS_HOSTNAME – The hostname of the DB instance. Amazon RDS console label – Endpoint (this is the hostname)
>
> RDS_PORT – The port on which the DB instance accepts connections. The default value varies between DB engines.
>      Amazon RDS console label – Port
>
> RDS_DB_NAME – The database name, ebdb.
>      Amazon RDS console label – DB Name
>
> RDS_USERNAME – The user name that you configured for your database.
>      Amazon RDS console label – Username
>
> RDS_PASSWORD – The password that you configured for your database.

```
private static Connection getRemoteConnection() {
    if (System.getenv("RDS_HOSTNAME") != null) {
      try {
      Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
      String dbName = System.getenv("RDS_DB_NAME");
      String userName = System.getenv("RDS_USERNAME");
      String password = System.getenv("RDS_PASSWORD");
      String hostname = System.getenv("RDS_HOSTNAME");
      String port = System.getenv("RDS_PORT");
      String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/" + dbName + "?user=" + userName + "&password=" + password;
      logger.trace("Getting remote connection with connection string from environment variables.");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);
      logger.info("Remote connection successful.");
      return con;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { logger.warn(e.toString());}
    catch (SQLException e) { logger.warn(e.toString());}
    }
    return null;
  }
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html#java-rds-javase

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to initialize them in /etc/environment? When I need to be sure an environment variable exists I make sure and add it there. All user shells will get that variable set that way.